# 3 subfigures, 2 vertically aligned and one hortizontally

Tags: vertical-alignment, subfloats

[image]

Hello,

Does anybody know how to vertically align two subfigures with another subfigure horizontally?

I mean i need to put two small images above each other beside another longer image as shown above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{cat1}}
        \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{cat2}}
        \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{cat3}}
    \label{fig:cat1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.   Cute cats ;-)

Comment: Okay, code added to the original post
Thanks for the edit :))

Comment: Shall the right picture automatically be scaled to the height of the both left ones (+some space for labels?)

Comment: No not needed to be automatically. you may say for cat 3 `\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth, height=0.8\linewidth]{cat3}`

Comment: The 'easiest' approach would be a tabular environment

Comment: By the way: `subfigure` package is deprecated. Use `subfig` instead

Comment: Great! it worked with the minipage idea, Thanks Christian and Mico :)